# Issue running a Rails 4 App on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

The app runs flawlessly in development.

I get an app crash error when I run the app on heroku.

With ruby '1.9.3' in the gemfile:

```
2013-03-07T17:52:54+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 6699 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-03-07T17:52:54+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2013-03-07T17:52:55+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: bin/rails: No such file or directory
2013-03-07T17:52:56+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-03-07T17:52:59+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 38670 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-03-07T17:53:00+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find railties (>= 0) amongst [Ascii85-1.0.2, activerecord-deprecated_finders-0.0.3, afm-0.2.0, angular-ui-bootstrap-rails-0.1.1, angularjs-rails-1.0.5, atomic-1.0.1, bigdecimal-1.1.0, bootstrap-sass-2.3.0.1, bootswatch-rails-0.4.0, builder-3.1.4, bundler-1.3.0.pre.5, coffee-script-2.2.0, coffee-script-source-1.5.0, erubis-2.7.0, execjs-1.4.0, hashery-2.1.0, hike-1.2.1, i18n-0.6.4, io-console-0.3, json-1.7.7, json-1.5.5, mail-2.5.3, mime-types-1.21, minitest-4.6.2, minitest-2.5.1, multi_json-1.6.1, pdf-reader-1.3.1, pg-0.14.1, polyglot-0.3.3, prawn-0.12.0, rack-1.5.2, rack-test-0.6.2, rake-10.0.3, rake-0.9.2.2, rdoc-3.12.2, rdoc-3.9.5, ruby-rc4-0.1.5, sass-3.2.6, sprockets-2.9.0, sprockets-rails-2.0.0.rc3, thor-0.17.0, thread_safe-0.1.0, tilt-1.3.4, treetop-1.4.12, ttfunk-1.0.3, tzinfo-0.3.35, uglifier-1.3.0] (Gem::LoadError)
2013-03-07T17:53:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
2013-03-07T17:53:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1231:in `gem'
2013-03-07T17:53:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   from bin/rails:22:in `<main>'
2013-03-07T17:53:02+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-03-07T17:53:02+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-03-07T17:53:02+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-03-07T17:53:09+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by brian@plexm.com
2013-03-07T17:53:10+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 11069 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-03-07T17:53:11+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find railties (>= 0) amongst [Ascii85-1.0.2, activerecord-deprecated_finders-0.0.3, afm-0.2.0, angular-ui-bootstrap-rails-0.1.1, angularjs-rails-1.0.5, atomic-1.0.1, bigdecimal-1.1.0, bootstrap-sass-2.3.0.1, bootswatch-rails-0.4.0, builder-3.1.4, bundler-1.3.0.pre.5, coffee-script-2.2.0, coffee-script-source-1.5.0, erubis-2.7.0, execjs-1.4.0, hashery-2.1.0, hike-1.2.1, i18n-0.6.4, io-console-0.3, json-1.7.7, json-1.5.5, mail-2.5.3, mime-types-1.21, minitest-4.6.2, minitest-2.5.1, multi_json-1.6.1, pdf-reader-1.3.1, pg-0.14.1, polyglot-0.3.3, prawn-0.12.0, rack-1.5.2, rack-test-0.6.2, rake-10.0.3, rake-0.9.2.2, rdoc-3.12.2, rdoc-3.9.5, ruby-rc4-0.1.5, sass-3.2.6, sprockets-2.9.0, sprockets-rails-2.0.0.rc3, thor-0.17.0, thread_safe-0.1.0, tilt-1.3.4, treetop-1.4.12, ttfunk-1.0.3, tzinfo-0.3.35, uglifier-1.3.0] (Gem::LoadError)
2013-03-07T17:53:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from bin/rails:22:in `<main>'
2013-03-07T17:53:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
2013-03-07T17:53:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1231:in `gem'
2013-03-07T17:53:12+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-03-07T17:53:12+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-03-07T17:53:15+00:00 heroku[run.3892]: Awaiting client
2013-03-07T17:53:15+00:00 heroku[run.3892]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2013-03-07T17:53:15+00:00 heroku[run.3892]: State changed from starting to up
2013-03-07T17:53:24+00:00 heroku[run.3892]: Client connection closed. Sending SIGHUP to all processes
2013-03-07T17:53:25+00:00 heroku[run.3892]: State changed from up to complete
2013-03-07T17:53:25+00:00 heroku[run.3892]: Process exited with status 0
2013-03-07T17:53:29+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=bpetro.herokuapp.com fwd="99.104.137.64" dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-03-07T17:53:30+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=bpetro.herokuapp.com fwd="99.104.137.64" dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-03-07T17:53:30+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=bpetro.herokuapp.com fwd="99.104.137.64" dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The log indicates that Heroku is trying to deploy the app using ruby 1.9.1.  Rails 4 requires ruby 1.9.3 minimum: https://blog.engineyard.com/2013/rails-4-changes

You need to update your `Gemfile` to specify 1.9.3:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions

Also try the steps in the Gist: https://gist.github.com/peter/3025502

Comment: I already tried with the first heroku instance's logs I posted. I made another heroku instance, with 1.9.3 added from the beginning. I still am having an issue. I posted the logs in my original post. Maybe because 1.9.1 is still being called somewhere?

Comment: I added a Gist to the answer of the steps taken to get Rails 4 to run on Heroku.  Hope that helps.

Comment: I want to note that someone else created an answer saying that they were experiencing the same issue. The post has since been deleted, likely because of it's lack of help.

Comment: No, it doesn’t indicate Ruby 1.9.1. The 1.9.1 in the path is the C API version the gems were installed using, which is used for 1.9.1–1.9.3. In fact, earlier in the path is, well, “ruby-1.9.3”. Further, [Heroku doesn’t even offer Ruby 1.9.1](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#ruby-versions).

Comment: My final solution was to create a new app, follow the posted gist from this post, and restart my app from there.

Comment: The real issue, I think, is that you need to include bin/rails in your git repo, instead if ignoring it in .gitignore