# Bundler error on Heroku running Rails 4 and Ruby 2.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, bundler, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

Attempting to deploy a very basic Rails 4.0.0 beta 1 app on Ruby 2.0.0 using Heroku Cedar. When I try and push to Heroku I get the following bundler error:

```
bin/bundle: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
Failed to install gems via Bundler.
```

Gemfile is as follows:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'

gem 'rails', '4.0.0.beta1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 2.2.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.0.1'
gem 'angularjs-rails', '~> 1.0.5'
gem 'lodash-rails'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0.beta1'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0.beta1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

group :test do
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.2.1'
end

group :test, :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

I don't get any bundler errors with `bundle install` when I run it locally using bundler 1.3.4

Anyone have any idea or experience with edge Rails on Heroku Cedar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was actually the 'bundle` executable in the bin directory, as soon as I removed 'bin/bundler' it deployed just fine.

Comment: Great to hear, WIN! Accept your own answer so this doesn't sit as an unanswered question :)

Answer (score 0):

[Use this gist to install a rails 4 app on heroku.](https://gist.github.com/peter/3025502)

I was unable to get it running on heroku with ruby 2.0. Using the above gist is my way of doing it until there is a clear way of upgrading smoothly to ruby 2.0.

[Here is the question from when I ran into issues.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15278099/issue-running-a-rails-4-app-on-heroku)

Comment: Dropped down to ruby 1.9.3 and went through all the steps outlines in that gist, I still get the same error though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a line with `ruby "2.0.0"` to the begin of your Gemfile.

For more informations go to the [heroku documentation](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2012/11/5/ruby-2-preview-on-heroku).

Comment: I did, it's even posted in my question.