# Rails Tutorial step 7 crashes on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

I have been following Michael Hartl's rails tutorial through step 7, and have gotten all components of the app to work locally, but the deployed app on Heroku always crashes.

Here are the logs:

```
2014-02-26T04:19:34.786658+00:00 heroku[run.3822]: Awaiting client
2014-02-26T04:19:34.815624+00:00 heroku[run.3822]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2014-02-26T04:19:36.369262+00:00 heroku[run.3822]: Process exited with status 127
2014-02-26T04:19:36.389193+00:00 heroku[run.3822]: State changed from up to complete
2014-02-26T04:19:34.961474+00:00 heroku[run.3822]: State changed from starting to up
2014-02-26T04:20:22.087742+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails console` by fuhr.8@osu.edu
2014-02-26T04:20:25.876786+00:00 heroku[run.3783]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails console`
2014-02-26T04:20:25.837657+00:00 heroku[run.3783]: Awaiting client
2014-02-26T04:20:26.058260+00:00 heroku[run.3783]: State changed from starting to up
2014-02-26T04:20:27.518272+00:00 heroku[run.3783]: State changed from up to complete
2014-02-26T04:20:27.505410+00:00 heroku[run.3783]: Process exited with status 127
2014-02-26T04:21:38.782040+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails console` by fuhr.8@osu.edu
2014-02-26T04:21:42.085570+00:00 heroku[run.7470]: Awaiting client
2014-02-26T04:21:42.125049+00:00 heroku[run.7470]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails console`
2014-02-26T04:21:42.249489+00:00 heroku[run.7470]: State changed from starting to up
2014-02-26T04:21:43.784776+00:00 heroku[run.7470]: Process exited with status 127
2014-02-26T04:21:43.798596+00:00 heroku[run.7470]: State changed from up to complete
2014-02-26T04:43:43.612458+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 56386 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2014-02-26T04:43:44.585171+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby1.9.1: No such file or directory
2014-02-26T04:43:45.929138+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2014-02-26T04:43:45.941056+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-02-26T04:43:40.552931+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-02-26T05:37:13.007353+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-02-26T05:37:16.508693+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 26146 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2014-02-26T05:37:17.617073+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby1.9.1: No such file or directory
2014-02-26T05:37:19.218670+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2014-02-26T05:37:19.236835+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-02-26T07:00:02.182689+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-02-26T07:00:04.979053+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 12026 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2014-02-26T07:00:05.752530+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby1.9.1: No such file or directory
2014-02-26T07:00:07.045969+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2014-02-26T07:00:07.059365+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-02-26T10:02:19.052437+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-02-26T10:02:23.089949+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 57792 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2014-02-26T10:02:24.030703+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby1.9.1: No such file or directory
2014-02-26T10:02:25.603050+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-02-26T10:02:25.586748+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2014-02-26T16:05:21.627569+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-02-26T16:05:25.560431+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 27681 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2014-02-26T16:05:26.740376+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby1.9.1: No such file or directory
2014-02-26T16:05:28.216181+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2014-02-26T16:05:28.231988+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-02-26T22:36:13.564272+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-02-26T22:36:16.731855+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 34034 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2014-02-26T22:36:17.624896+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby1.9.1: No such file or directory
2014-02-26T22:36:18.854003+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2014-02-26T22:36:18.866282+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-02-27T05:30:16.208399+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 3741 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2014-02-27T05:30:17.063457+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby1.9.1: No such file or directory
2014-02-27T05:30:18.435612+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2014-02-27T05:30:18.448423+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-02-27T11:05:18.144493+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 36192 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2014-02-27T11:05:18.872510+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby1.9.1: No such file or directory
2014-02-27T11:05:20.510801+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-02-27T11:05:20.492993+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2014-02-27T11:05:14.787786+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-02-27T16:44:18.575729+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 59299 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2014-02-27T16:44:19.348049+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby1.9.1: No such file or directory
2014-02-27T16:44:20.563995+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2014-02-27T16:44:20.574112+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-02-27T16:44:15.757618+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-02-27T22:12:44.532484+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-02-27T22:12:47.456754+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 11197 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2014-02-27T22:12:48.278763+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby1.9.1: No such file or directory
2014-02-27T22:12:49.559838+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-02-27T22:12:49.550175+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2014-02-28T04:40:11.057321+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-02-28T04:40:13.639647+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 43182 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2014-02-28T04:40:14.310788+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby1.9.1: No such file or directory
2014-02-28T04:40:15.409531+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2014-02-28T04:40:15.415639+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-02-28T10:18:46.151906+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-02-28T10:18:49.285579+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 21759 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2014-02-28T10:18:50.153912+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby1.9.1: No such file or directory
2014-02-28T10:18:51.356227+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2014-02-28T10:18:51.367781+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-02-28T14:45:52+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-02-28T14:46:36.514961+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 91d187e by fuhr.8@osu.edu
2014-02-28T14:46:36.515061+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v8 created by fuhr.8@osu.edu
2014-02-28T14:46:36+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2014-02-28T14:46:37.248946+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-02-28T14:46:40.588535+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 46663 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2014-02-28T14:46:41.492435+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby1.9.1: No such file or directory
2014-02-28T14:46:42.781218+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-02-28T14:46:42.782763+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-02-28T14:46:42.771936+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2014-02-28T14:46:45.778732+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 52270 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2014-02-28T14:46:46.748933+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby1.9.1: No such file or directory
2014-02-28T14:46:47.570899+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by fuhr.8@osu.edu
2014-02-28T14:46:48.061424+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2014-02-28T14:46:48.068677+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-02-28T14:46:51.380409+00:00 heroku[run.4658]: State changed from starting to up
2014-02-28T14:46:51.774878+00:00 heroku[run.4658]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2014-02-28T14:46:51.740375+00:00 heroku[run.4658]: Awaiting client
2014-02-28T14:46:53.498224+00:00 heroku[run.4658]: Process exited with status 127
2014-02-28T14:46:53.509618+00:00 heroku[run.4658]: State changed from up to complete
2014-02-28T14:47:01.736120+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=intense-temple-2285.herokuapp.com request_id=827f680b-f7fb-4da1-a1dc-fe11d9d6e5b9 fwd="140.254.150.23" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-02-28T14:47:07.788770+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/signup host=intense-temple-2285.herokuapp.com request_id=4803c37e-9ba6-4ef7-a8fe-652658b3e3be fwd="140.254.150.23" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-02-28T14:47:14.910081+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=intense-temple-2285.herokuapp.com request_id=e7923adc-0f71-42d8-b325-fb07356b53f1 fwd="140.254.150.23" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-02-28T14:47:16.010245+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=intense-temple-2285.herokuapp.com request_id=e040f7ad-431a-4d27-9405-ccda62fe44fa fwd="140.254.150.23" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-02-28T14:47:08.047991+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=intense-temple-2285.herokuapp.com request_id=8c1f7c8b-8a07-41bd-988a-872f07ed457a fwd="140.254.150.23" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

with the error messages in the last 5 lines. Does anyone know what is failing and how to fix it? The github repo is here: https://github.com/afuhrtrumpet/sample_app

Comment: Are you using `rvm`, `rbenv`, or anything else to manage your ruby version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you can solve your issue by doing the following:

replace "#!/usr/bin/env ruby1.9.1" => "#!/usr/bin/env ruby" in 3 files:

```
bin/bundle
bin/rails
bin/rake
```

I found this here if you'd like more information:
[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17712814/simple-heroku-rails-4-app-crashing)

Mike Riley

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I get an internal server error now though when trying to visit the signup page. Do you know what might be the source of that? The error doesn't happen for any other pages.

Comment: Can you post the logs?  Sounds like it is a 500 internal server error.  The logs may help to diagnose it.  May be a good idea to open a separate issue since this one is resolved.  Just send me a link to the new issue and I can take a look.

Comment: Turns out I just had to run rake db:migrate, thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

2014-02-28T14:46:46.748933+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby1.9.1: No such file or directory

That line is your actual error.

I had the same thing using Ruby 2.0 with a Rails 4 project.   Somehow your bin directory kind of got messed up.   When you do your push, Heroku can't actually run any command within your bin directory because it doesn't exist there.

When I researched this answer, the resolution that worked for me was this simple:

```
run rake rails:update:bin on your local project.
git add and commit and push
git push heroku master
```

Worked for me.